# Kasteleyn orientation in Dimer model

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, ising-model, statistical-mechanics

**Some Background**: The problem of dimer configurations or [perfect matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_matching) occurs naturally when a diatomic gas is adsorbed onto a crystalline substrate and was first discussed by [Rushbrooke and Fowler](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1937/tf/tf9373301272). It can be summarized as follows

```
Given some lattice, the task is to find the number of ways that its vertices can be completely covered 
by non-overlapping dimers that each occupy two neighboring vertices.
```

This problem was solved independently by [Kasteleyn](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0031891461900635), [Fisher](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.124.1664), and [Temperley](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14786436108243366?journalCode=tphm19).

**Solution strategy**: Let the weight of horizontal and vertical dimers on a [planner graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) $\Gamma_{mn}$ be respectively $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$. As an example of such $(z_{1})^{4}(z_{2})^{8}$ is shown below:

[image]

The goal is then to compute the dimer partition function, given by

$$Z_{\mathrm{dimer}}(N_{1},N_{2}) = \sum_{N_{1},N_{2}}g(N_{1},N_{2})z_{1}^{N_{1}}z_{2}^{N_{2}}$$
where, $g(N_{1},N_{2})$  be the number of dimer coverings of $\Gamma_{mn}$ using $N_1$ horizontal and $N_2$ vertical dimers.

The insight of Kasteleyn is to show that,

$$Z_{\mathrm{dimer}}(N_{1},N_{2}) = \mathrm{Pf}(A)$$

Where $\mathrm{Pf}(A)$ is the [Pfaffian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian) of some **weighted skew-symmetric adjacency matrix** known to be the Kasteleyn matrix, given by

$$\mathrm{Pf}(A) = \frac{1}{2^{N}N!}\sum_{\sigma}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) a_{\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}}\cdots a_{\sigma_{2n-1},\sigma_{2n}}$$

Where, the sum is over all permutations $\{1,2,\cdots,2n\}$ and $\mathrm{sgn} = \pm 1$, denotes the signature of $\sigma$. The celebrated [FKT algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKT_algorithm) allows us to express the dimer partition function of a certain class of graphs as a Pfaffian as follows

Enumerate the vertices of $\Gamma$ by $1, 2,\cdots,2n$, and fix an arbitrary orientation $K$ of the edges of $\Gamma$. Let $A^K = (a^{K})_{ij}$ denote the associated weighted skew-adjacency matrix; this is the $2n \times 2n$ skew-symmetric matrix whose coefficients are given by

$$a_{ij}^{K} = \sum_{e}\varepsilon_{ij}^{K}(e)\nu(e)$$
Where, $\nu(e)$ is the weight associated with the edge $e$, and the sum is taken over all edges connecting vertices $i$ and $j$, and

$$\varepsilon_{ij}^{K}(e) = \begin{cases}
  +1  & \text{if $e$ is oriented by $K$ from $i$ to $j$;} \\
  -1  & \text{if $e$ is oriented by $K$ from $j$ to $i$;} \\ 
  0 & n \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
An example taken from [Cimasoni](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4631) is given below,

[image]

Using $\epsilon^{K}_{ij}$ into the definition of $Pf(A)$, we can write,

$$Pf(A) = \sum_{\mathcal{D}\in \sigma}(-1)^{\sigma}\epsilon_{\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}}^{K}\cdots \epsilon_{\sigma_{n-1}\sigma_{n}}^{K}\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\nu(\sigma_{i},\sigma_{i+1})$$

Where the sum has taken on all dimer configurations $\mathcal{D}$ (perfect matching) on the lattice $\Gamma$. If we let,
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon^{K}(\mathcal{D}) = (-1)^{\sigma}\epsilon_{\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}}^{K}\cdots \epsilon_{\sigma_{n-1}\sigma_{n}}^{K}
\end{equation}

**Proposition:** $\varepsilon^{K}(\mathcal{D})$ does not depends do any dimer configuration $\mathcal{D}$. Let $\varepsilon^{K}(\mathcal{D})$  and $\varepsilon^{K}(\mathcal{D'})$ is defined for two dimer configuration $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{D}'$ respectively. If $\varepsilon^{K}$ is independent of any dimer configurations then
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon^{K}(\mathcal{D})\varepsilon^{K}(\mathcal{D'}) = 1
\end{equation}
Which is the amount to show that

\begin{equation}
\varepsilon^{K}(\mathcal{D})\varepsilon^{K}(\mathcal{D'}) = \prod_{i} (-1)^{\sum_{C_{i}}(n^{K}(C_{i})+1)}
\end{equation}
Where $n^{K}(C)$ is defined as the number of edges oriented opposite to the chosen orientation of $C$. Showing the above equation immediately leads to the Kasteleyn theorem, which says that $n^{K}(\partial f)$ is odd, for some face $f$.

**Proof:** The proof following [N Reshetikhin](https://tqfts.com/dimer-models-in-statistical-mechanics/) goes as follows,
\begin{eqnarray}
\varepsilon^{K}(\mathcal{D})\varepsilon^{K}(\mathcal{D'}) & = & (-1)^{\sigma}(-1)^{\sigma'} \epsilon_{\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}}^{K}\cdots \epsilon_{\sigma_{n-1}\sigma_{n}}^{K}\epsilon_{\sigma'_{1}\sigma'_{2}}^{K}\cdots \epsilon_{\sigma'_{n-1}\sigma'_{n}}^{K}
\end{eqnarray}
And then shows that the signature of *transition cycle* $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are related by the $l$ even transposition such that,
\begin{equation}
(-1)^{\sigma}(-1)^{\sigma'} = (-1)^{l+1}
\end{equation}
for a cycle of even length $l$.

**Question:** In fact what I found is that ($-1)^{\sigma}(-1)^{\sigma'} = (-1)^{l-1}$. My final result agrees with the stated theorem yet I am not sure how Reshetikhin found $l+1$. I tried to link the relevant papers to this question. Hopefully, someone would be able to point out what is actually happening here. Putting another way,

> the signature of a transposition cycle of length l is $(-1)^{(l+1)}$, yet I found $(-1)^{(l-1)}$. Since the length of the transition cycles are even hence (-1)^{l} = 1. So the final parity is -1 for both cases. Does it mean the signature of a transposition cycle of length l can be either $(-1)^{(l+1)}$ or $(-1)^{(l-1)}$?

**Connection to Ising Model:** Once one gets the Kasteleyn orientation, the partition function immediately follows (after doing some heavy linear algebra)

$$ Z_{\mathrm{dimer}} = \prod_{k=1}^{m/2}\prod_{\ell=1}^{n}2 \left(x^{2}\cos^{2}\frac{k\pi}{m+1}+y^{2}\cos^{2}\frac{\ell\pi}{n+1}\right)  $$

This remarkable formula gives the number of perfect matching on a 2D square lattice with open boundary conditions. Which in thermodynamic limit gives a hint with the solution of 2D Ising model.

2D Ising model (without magnetic field) is related to the dimer model. In 1939 Van der Wearden showed that the Ising model partition function can be considered as enumerating the number of loops in 2D (see [Feynman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201360764)). Which was used by Kac and Ward to give [Combinatorial proof](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.88.1332) of the Ising model. The idea of Kac and Ward is to write the Ising model partition function as the square root of the determinant of a matrix $A$.

\begin{equation}
Z_{\mathrm{Ising}} = \sqrt{A}
\end{equation}

Interestingly, the Kac-Ward proof had a famous mistake which was later corrected by Feynman using a [beautiful formula](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2015/06/feynmans_fabulous_formula.html) (which he never published in any paper except discussing in his statistical mechanics lectures).

Looking at the above expression, one can see that Pfaffian is exactly the square root of some determinant.

$$\mathrm{Pf} = \sqrt{\mathrm{Det}A} $$
or
$$Z_{\mathrm{Ising}} = Z_{\mathrm{dimer}} = \sqrt{\mathrm{Det}A^{K}}$$

Where $A^{K}$ is the Kasteleyn matrix.

Kasteleyn, Fisher, and Temperley independently mapped the Ising model partition function into a dimer partition function and then solve the Ising problem. In order to understand their proof, the theorem I mentioned plays a crucial role and that is the reason for posting this question in PSE.

Comment: Aren't $(-1)^{l-1}$ and $(-1)^{l+1}$ equal?

Comment: They are, my question why did they wrote it as $(-)^l+1$ instead of other way round. If both this expressions are the choice of convention, then it's alright